# Windows Azure PDT eclipse PHP Setting up

Tags: php, windows, eclipse, azure

I am just starting with Windows Azure using PHP SDK. I installed Azure plugin in eclipse using this [link](http://www.windowsazure4e.org/download/). Got my Compute and Storage emulators running. Now when I try to run the new project using the option shown below, nothing happens!

[image: Screen shot]

When I try to select a particular script and run it as "PHP Windows Azure Page", I get this error:

> Development Fabric is not Completely Started

Please note that I had changed my port number of Zend and my Compute and Storage Emulator are working fine. Still I am getting this error. 
Any help will be appreciated...